# How to join Azure AD with office 365 domain

Tags: office-365, office, azure, office365apis

I have an office 365 developer account with a specific domain name. I also have an organization sponsored azure account via same MSDN. I would like to join both the domains/AD's so i can develop apps based on ADAL. Please explain me how i can do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an excellent reference down below and tried it practically.

http://www.edutech.me.uk/microsoft/identity-and-access-management/active-directory/link-microsoft-office-365-organization-account-to-windows-azure-subscription/

let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: Links can break over time. Provide a summary.